# Are these dmesg gaps causing my 12.04 to boot up slowly?

Tags: 12.04, networking, boot, fglrx

I am having a really slow boot on ubuntu 12.04.

Below is my `dmesg` log's major gaps:

```
[3.704928] EXT4-fs (sda6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[26.933486] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[26.963373] udevd[521]: starting version 175
.......
[30.610196] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x48
[30.610219] fb0: VESA VGA frame buffer device
[55.783563] EXT4-fs (sda6): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[55.896936] init: failsafe main process (862) killed by TERM signal
.......
[57.789828] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:fc21000, size:3df000 
[57.789831] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:1fffb000, size:5000 
[62.734097] retire_capture_urb: 33 callbacks suppressed
```

And the entire log starting from the fist major jump:

```
[    2.321228] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    3.704928] EXT4-fs (sda6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   26.933486] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   26.963373] udevd[521]: starting version 175
[   26.997901] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   27.108201] Adding 4189180k swap on /dev/sda7.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:4189180k 
[   27.179344] fglrx: module license 'Proprietary. (C) 2002 - ATI Technologies, Starnberg, GERMANY' taints kernel.
[   27.179349] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   27.223563] lib80211: common routines for IEEE802.11 drivers
[   27.223567] lib80211_crypt: registered algorithm 'NULL'
[   27.230060] wmi: Mapper loaded
[   27.282402] [fglrx] Maximum main memory to use for locked dma buffers: 3789 MBytes.
[   27.282841] [fglrx]   vendor: 1002 device: 9552 count: 1
[   27.288436] [fglrx] ioport: bar 1, base 0xde00, size: 0x100
[   27.288455] pci 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[   27.288462] pci 0000:01:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   27.288748] [fglrx] Kernel PAT support is enabled
[   27.288774] [fglrx] module loaded - fglrx 8.96.4 [Mar 12 2012] with 1 minors
[   27.317960] type=1400 audit(1340701603.968:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=592 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   27.318412] type=1400 audit(1340701603.968:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=592 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   27.318667] type=1400 audit(1340701603.968:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=592 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   27.320618] wl 0000:0c:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
[   27.320633] wl 0000:0c:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   27.345899] lib80211_crypt: registered algorithm 'TKIP'
[   27.671729] eth1: Broadcom BCM4315 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 5.100.82.38
[   27.679365] acpi device:36: registered as cooling_device2
[   27.679963] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A03:00/device:34/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input6
[   27.680139] ACPI: Video Device [VID] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[   27.680197] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[   27.689258] dcdbas dcdbas: Dell Systems Management Base Driver (version 5.6.0-3.2)
[   27.909956] input: Dell WMI hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input7
[   27.920377] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 21 (level, low) -> IRQ 21
[   27.920457] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 47 for MSI/MSI-X
[   27.920493] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   27.925526] udevd[535]: renamed network interface eth1 to wlan0
[   27.926453] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   27.935642] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device  (046d:0990)
[   27.965100] input: HDA Intel Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
[   27.965208] input: HDA Intel Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
[   27.968986] input: UVC Camera (046d:0990) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/input/input10
[   27.969151] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   27.969154] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   28.115197] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[   28.524059] input: PS/2 Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio2/input/input11
[   28.550620] input: AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint as /devices/platform/i8042/serio2/input/input12
[   30.608553] vesafb: mode is 1024x768x32, linelength=4096, pages=0
[   30.608556] vesafb: scrolling: redraw
[   30.608559] vesafb: Truecolor: size=0:8:8:8, shift=0:16:8:0
[   30.608567] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,400000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   30.608571] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,200000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   30.608574] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,100000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   30.608578] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,80000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   30.608581] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,40000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   30.608585] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,20000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   30.608588] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,10000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   30.608591] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,8000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   30.608595] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,4000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   30.608598] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,2000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   30.608601] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,1000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   30.609975] vesafb: framebuffer at 0xe0000000, mapped to 0xffffc90005200000, using 3072k, total 3072k
[   30.610196] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x48
[   30.610219] fb0: VESA VGA frame buffer device
[   55.783563] EXT4-fs (sda6): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   55.896936] init: failsafe main process (862) killed by TERM signal
[   55.970556] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   56.037984] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[   56.038033] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   56.038035] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   56.038039] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   56.038041] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   56.038971] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   56.039213] type=1400 audit(1340701632.688:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=943 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   56.040322] type=1400 audit(1340701632.692:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=943 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   56.075476] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   56.075479] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   56.093563] type=1400 audit(1340701632.744:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" pid=976 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   56.097218] type=1400 audit(1340701632.748:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=977 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   56.097697] type=1400 audit(1340701632.748:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=977 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   56.097962] type=1400 audit(1340701632.748:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=977 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   56.119273] type=1400 audit(1340701632.768:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" pid=980 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   56.119825] type=1400 audit(1340701632.768:12): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*" pid=980 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   56.120496] type=1400 audit(1340701632.772:13): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/bin/evince" pid=978 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   56.126495] type=1400 audit(1340701632.776:14): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/bin/evince//launchpad_integration" pid=978 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   56.167916] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   56.167924] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   56.167925] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   56.171308] sky2 0000:09:00.0: eth0: enabling interface
[   56.172168] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   56.600301] fglrx_pci 0000:01:00.0: irq 48 for MSI/MSI-X
[   56.601010] [fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1185
[   56.601125] [fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1186
[   56.601232] [fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1187
[   56.601374] [fglrx] IRQ 48 Enabled
[   57.789816] [fglrx] Gart USWC size:1236 M.
[   57.789820] [fglrx] Gart cacheable size:489 M.
[   57.789826] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Shared offset:0, size:1000000 
[   57.789828] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:fc21000, size:3df000 
[   57.789831] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:1fffb000, size:5000 
[   62.734097] retire_capture_urb: 33 callbacks suppressed
```

---

After booting into a Kubuntu live cd and running `fsck` on `sda6` my new `dmesg` log is as follows:
it's a lot better, but there is still some things that need fixing...

```
[    2.207381] usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-realtek
[    3.022438] EXT4-fs (sda6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   24.927346] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   24.947348] udevd[528]: starting version 175
[   24.989016] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   25.114602] Adding 4189180k swap on /dev/sda7.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:4189180k 
[   25.224313] fglrx: module license 'Proprietary. (C) 2002 - ATI Technologies, Starnberg, GERMANY' taints kernel.
[   25.224318] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   25.227858] wmi: Mapper loaded
[   25.352057] EXT4-fs (sda6): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   25.355222] [fglrx] Maximum main memory to use for locked dma buffers: 3789 MBytes.
[   25.355665] [fglrx]   vendor: 1002 device: 9552 count: 1
[   25.357794] acpi device:36: registered as cooling_device2
[   25.358339] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A03:00/device:34/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input6
[   25.358403] ACPI: Video Device [VID] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[   25.358460] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[   25.359042] [fglrx] ioport: bar 1, base 0xde00, size: 0x100
[   25.359060] pci 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[   25.359066] pci 0000:01:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   25.359351] [fglrx] Kernel PAT support is enabled
[   25.359381] [fglrx] module loaded - fglrx 8.96.4 [Mar 12 2012] with 1 minors
[   25.368882] lib80211: common routines for IEEE802.11 drivers
[   25.368887] lib80211_crypt: registered algorithm 'NULL'
[   25.401959] wl 0000:0c:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
[   25.401974] wl 0000:0c:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   25.427178] lib80211_crypt: registered algorithm 'TKIP'
[   25.584831] dcdbas dcdbas: Dell Systems Management Base Driver (version 5.6.0-3.2)
[   25.746084] type=1400 audit(1340791412.412:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=650 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   25.746547] type=1400 audit(1340791412.412:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=650 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   25.746801] type=1400 audit(1340791412.412:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=650 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   25.764322] eth1: Broadcom BCM4315 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 5.100.82.38
[   25.798103] input: Dell WMI hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input7
[   25.865145] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 21 (level, low) -> IRQ 21
[   25.865372] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 47 for MSI/MSI-X
[   25.865409] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   25.876496] udevd[542]: renamed network interface eth1 to wlan0
[   25.921141] input: HDA Intel Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
[   25.921292] input: HDA Intel Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
[   26.061800] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[   26.061903] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   26.061905] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   26.061909] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   26.061912] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   26.062236] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   26.088065] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   26.088072] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   26.088074] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   26.118242] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   26.118246] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   26.134631] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   26.207491] init: failsafe main process (840) killed by TERM signal
[   26.235813] type=1400 audit(1340791412.900:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=914 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   26.236834] type=1400 audit(1340791412.904:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=914 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   26.318889] input: PS/2 Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio2/input/input10
[   26.346789] input: AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint as /devices/platform/i8042/serio2/input/input11
[   26.616832] type=1400 audit(1340791413.284:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=962 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   26.617434] type=1400 audit(1340791413.284:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=962 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   26.617705] type=1400 audit(1340791413.284:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=962 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   26.618409] type=1400 audit(1340791413.284:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" pid=961 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   26.630449] type=1400 audit(1340791413.296:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" pid=965 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   26.649811] sky2 0000:09:00.0: eth0: enabling interface
[   26.651318] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   27.402907] vesafb: mode is 1024x768x32, linelength=4096, pages=0
[   27.402910] vesafb: scrolling: redraw
[   27.402913] vesafb: Truecolor: size=0:8:8:8, shift=0:16:8:0
[   27.402921] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,400000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   27.402925] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,200000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   27.402929] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,100000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   27.402932] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,80000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   27.402935] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,40000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   27.402939] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,20000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   27.402942] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,10000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   27.402945] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,8000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   27.402949] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,4000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   27.402952] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,2000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   27.402955] mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,1000 old: write-back new: write-combining
[   27.403550] vesafb: framebuffer at 0xe0000000, mapped to 0xffffc90005380000, using 3072k, total 3072k
[   27.404339] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x48
[   27.404362] fb0: VESA VGA frame buffer device
[   28.122642] fglrx_pci 0000:01:00.0: irq 48 for MSI/MSI-X
[   28.123347] [fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1182
[   28.123472] [fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1183
[   28.123566] [fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1184
[   28.123711] [fglrx] IRQ 48 Enabled
[   29.455557] [fglrx] Gart USWC size:1236 M.
[   29.455561] [fglrx] Gart cacheable size:489 M.
[   29.455567] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Shared offset:0, size:1000000 
[   29.455570] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:fc21000, size:3df000 
[   29.455573] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:1fffb000, size:5000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I woudld run a fsck on SDA6, looks like it got mouted read only. This could be a sign that it found errors. If you boot into ubuntu successfully, then unmount SDA6 if possible and run a fsck on it. If you cannot unmount SDA6 because it's mounted at / or someother place that is essential then run a boot CD to do the fsck.

Comment: I ran fsck on SDA6, please view my new dmesg log and see how you can help :)